# How to enable LDAP connection for MySQL using java?

Tags: java, mysql, ldap

I am trying to authenticate users from LDAP server to use the database using JAVA code. So far I have authentication working I just need to know how to get the roles from the LDAP?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you have any code examples of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the MySQL 5.5 manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pam-authentication-plugin.html), the way to get different MySQL roles for different users depending on their LDAP group membership is to use the PAM authentication plugin's proxy user mechanism.  The manual includes extensive material on how to do this, and it would be pointless to repeat it all here.

However, you don't configure this from Java, and the mechanisms are not Java / JDBC specific.

Comment: Thanks, will take  a look at it.